# How to get objects and mesh object vertices from camera view with Python in Blender 2.8

Tags: python, camera

### What I want to do

1. I want to change the power of only the light object visible in the camera view.
2. I want to remove vertices to mesh objects in visible in the camera view. Not remove mesh objects, only remove view vertices.

### Question

1. How to get light objects visible in the camera view with Python.
2. How to get vertices in mesh objects  visible in the camera view with Python.

### Image

I want to get **Only left light object**.

[image: L]

I want to get **Only inside camera view vertices**

[image: M]

I can write Python but I'm not familiar with Blender.
So I'm more glad if I can get it with a script.